# cors-anywhere Page Dependecies (i.e. css, js, etc)

Tags: node.js, cors-anywhere

I am working with cors-anywhere on my localhost. I have the following server.js file...

```
var host = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';
var port = process.env.PORT || 1234;
var cors_proxy = require('cors-anywhere');

cors_proxy.createServer({
    httpProxyOptions: {
        secure: false
    }
}).listen(port, host, function() {
     console.log('listening...');
});
```

This works and is proxying the initial request when going to:

http://localhost:1234/https://proxy-domain/page

The issue is that on the page I am browsing/being proxied to there are dependent files (i.e., css, javascript, images, etc) that are not being loaded because they are not being proxied appropriately. Looking at my browsers network tab the dependent files are trying to be downloaded from...

**http://localhost:12345**/sample-image.gif

Really the url should be...

**https://proxy-domain**/sample-image.gif

How can I configure cors-anywhere to proxy all subsequent requests to the appropriate target url?

Comment: Did you try `http://localhost:1234/https://proxy-domain/sample-image.gif` ?

Comment: @hurricane, yep if I manually put in a dependent file (http://localhost:1234/https://proxy-domain/sample-image.gif) in my browser the file is returned as expected.

Comment: can you add HTML example please?

Comment: I guess you need to parse the HTML and figure out url's and prepend the proxy-domain to it

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere#server) you can set `redirectSameOrigin` to `true`, which will redirect requests to the same origin instead of proxying them.

```
cors_proxy.createServer({
  redirectSameOrigin: true,
  httpProxyOptions: {
    secure: false
  }
})
```